# CSS angle a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside another div and I am trying to angle the div so the left side is touch the left side and the right side is touching the top. Is there away to do with CSS?

Here is my code:

```
.background { 
    background-color:black; 
    height:368px; 
}

.sold { 
    background-color:red; 
    font-size:26px; 
    width:200px; 
    text-align:center; 
    height:40px; 
    color:white; 
    line-height:40px;
}

<div class="background">

<div class="sold">Sold Out</div>

</div>
```

Here is my jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vakcgvtu/

Comment: so just the right side of the div is touching the top, so the div is on an angle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `transform` for this:

```css
.background {
    background-color:black;
    height:368px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sold {
    background-color:red;
    font-size:26px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    height:40px;
    color:white;
    line-height:40px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 37px;
    left: -43px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
    <div class="sold">Sold Out</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I am looking for. How would i eliminate the extra space, so the red goes all the away across?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and simple actually.

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/vakcgvtu/4/

```css
.background {
    background-color:black;
    height:368px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sold {
    background-color:red;
    font-size:26px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    height:40px;
    color:white;
    line-height:40px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: 30px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
    <div class="sold">Sold Out</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sweet! can I move it to the left side?

Answer (score 1):

Here, I changed you fiddle with `transform rotate` and `position relative` CSS.

### **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vakcgvtu/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/vakcgvtu/2/

```
.sold {
    background-color:red;
    font-size:26px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    height:40px;
    color:white;
    line-height:40px;
    left: -50px;
    top: 30px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position: relative;
```